# Force a line break after space in words in element

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview, html-table

I have a table/grid view and in the `<td>` there are 2 words like `"C2 Sunday"`. I want a line break up after C2 and it appears like,

```
 C2
Sunday
```

Is it possible to do that? 
Kindly help me with this. 
Now it displays like "`C2 Sunday`" and i want like above.

Comment: i am displaying data using eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use HTML `<br>` Tag to break like
 C2 `<br>`  Sunday

without Inverted Commas

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `</br>` like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>C2 </br> Sunday</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

make a CSS rule on td and give css property
word-break:break-all;

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for line break:

```
<html>
```

To break lines
in a text,
use the br element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<Itemtemplate>
<%# ((string)Eval("C2")).Replace("\n", "<br/>") %></Itemtemplate>

<Itemtemplate>
<%# FormatString(Eval("Sunday")) %></Itemtemplate>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using css grid
I have done like this

```
<somegriditem>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</somegriditem>
```

In the css

```
{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
```